# Bypass Chromium Logon / User / Password Prompt using Raspberry PI

Tags: google-chrome, raspberry-pi, chromium

I am trying to setup a display without a mouse/keyboard using a raspberry pi in a kind of "kiosk" mode.

The page I want to be loaded is a Microsoft Reporting Services page which requires windows authentication. I have been able to save the username/password in Chromium but the prompt still appears and I have to click ok.

Is there some way to bypass this?

Comment: Can you schedule tasks on a raspberry pi?

Comment: I'm sure you can, but that wont work in my scenario (I have a special distribution of linux installed which is completely looked down and essentially boots straight to a full screen chromium session with no access to the underlying operating system).

Comment: What about chrome extensions? I'm sure a macro could take care of this.

Comment: You know there is a Raspberry PI SE.....

Comment: @mdpc i consider this to be a chromium question rather than a Pi question